# connecting access 2013 with netbeans 7.2.1

Tags: java, database, netbeans, ms-access-2013

i have Microsoft access 2013 and net beans 7.2.1
how can i create and connect database using netbeans 7.2.1 
i have three data Name.getText(),Address.getText(),ContactNumber.getText()
that i am getting from GUI.
all i want to do is put this data from GUI to database.
i tried searching the net but it was too confusing or too specific
any help ?
i saw the following example but i am not sure if its for 2013 access or not

```
jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=C:\\db1.mdb
```

and i want to do it with relative path

Comment: When you say "create and connect database" do you mean that you want to create a new database file from within your Java code, or do you mean "create a connection (to an existing database file)"? Also, when you say that you want to use a "relative path", do you mean "relative to the folder in which the curently-executing Java code resides"?

Comment: i guess creating is not feasible so yea creating a connecting and inserting data into database
Also relative path means that my db file is in same folder where my code is and it should not matter if i am moving my folder to some other computer or place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is about as simplified as it gets. I tested this under NetBeans 7.4 and it works for me.

Notes:

The Access database file (Database1.accdb) that gets updated resides in the same folder as the `.class` file. For me that is

> C:\Users\Gord\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AccessTest\build\classes\accesstest

You may find that NetBeans also requires a copy of the .accdb file in the source folder, which in my case is

> C:\Users\Gord\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AccessTest\src\accesstest

but that is *not* the database file that gets updated. (I tried removing the copy in `src\...` but that also removed the copy in `build\...`. It seems that NetBeans does some automatic syncing of files in those two locations.)

This makes me question whether it is all that wise to depend on the data file residing in the same folder as the `.class` file. Depending on the way an application is deployed, the user may not have read/write access to the folder, or if the `.class` file lives inside a `.jar` file then the "path to the `.class` file" may not mean what you assume it does.

Anyway, the code is:

```java
package accesstest;

import java.io.File;
import java.sql.*;

public class AccessTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // find the folder in which this class currently lives
        //   ref: http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-get-example/get-class-location.shtml
        final java.net.URL classLocationURL;
        final String classLocation = AccessTest.class.getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class";
        final ClassLoader loader = AccessTest.class.getClassLoader();
        classLocationURL = loader.getResource(classLocation);

        File classFile = new File(classLocationURL.toString().substring(6));  // remove "file:/" prefix
        String codePath = classFile.getParent();

        Connection con;
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:odbc:" +
                    "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" +
                    "Dbq=" + codePath + "\\Database1.accdb;");
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(
                    "INSERT INTO ContactInfo (FullName, Address, ContactNumber) " +
                    "VALUES (?,?,?)");
            ps.setString(1, "Gord Thompson");
            ps.setString(2, "Canada");
            ps.setString(3, "111-222-3333");
            ps.executeUpdate();
            ps.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```